# Three ways to create a range, hash, array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am doing a tutorial course on ruby and it asks for 3 ways to create range, hash, array.

I can only think of 2: `(1..3)` and `Range.new(1,3)` (and similarly for hash and array).

What is the third way?

The tutorial in question is [The Odin Project](http://www.theodinproject.com/ruby-programming/ruby-building-blocks)

Answer (score 3):

Ranges may be constructed using the **s..e** and **s...e** literals, or with **::new**.

Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. 
Those created using ... exclude the end value. When used as an iterator, ranges return each value in the sequence.

```
(0..2) == (0..2)            #=> true
(0..2) == Range.new(0,2)    #=> true
(0..2) == (0...2)           #=> false
```

[Read More Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can also make a exclusive range, using `(1...4)`, which if turned into an array would become `[1, 2, 3]`

`(1..3)` is an inclusive range, so it contains all numbers, from 1 to 3, but if you used `(1...3)`, having 3 dots instead of 2 makes it exclusive, so it contains all numbers from 1, up to but not including 3.

As for arrays and hashes, #to_a, [Array#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D), #to_h, and [Hash#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) will work.

```
(1..3).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3]

Array[1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]

[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]].to_h
=> {1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6}

Hash[ [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] ]
=> {1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6}
```

But they are probably looking for [Array#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) and [Hash#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) on the array and hash part.

Comment: That's probably not what I'm looking for, since they are asking for 3 ways to create a Array / Hash as well. What's the third besides `[1,2,3]` and `Array.new`?

Comment: I updated my answer to answer the other part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

For Arrays there's [`Array::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-c-5B-5D) (example taken directly from the docs):

```
Array.[]( 1, 'a', /^A/ ) # => [1, "a", /^A/]
Array[ 1, 'a', /^A/ ]    # => [1, "a", /^A/]
[ 1, 'a', /^A/ ]         # => [1, "a", /^A/]
```

Similarly there's [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D). Not sure about [Ranges](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html); in fact, the docs (as far as I can tell) only mention literals and `Range::new`.

I can't see why you'd use these over a literal, but there you go.

Comment: I just found out that `new.array = %w("foo bar")` works as well. How about that? (And any idea on what `w` stands for?)

Comment: `w` means 'whitespace separated'.  The `%` notation is pretty slick once you start using it.  [Here is a list of the available modifiers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation), they make it even more useful.

Comment: @Anh Yeah, can't believe I forgot about that one. I use it all the time.